# Exam Application Programming Online Test javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to an online test sample applicatio with java script & I am facing some problem with the increment value of correct variable .The result of the increment value showing some strange value. If anyone can help me i can give y whole demo code

```
function checkAnswer(result,id,corrected)
   {
    var value;
      var choice=document.getElementsByName('choice');
      for(var i=0;i<choice.length;i++)                               //checkAnswer() function e problem ache 
      {
        if(choice[i].checked)
        {
           value=choice[i].value;
        }
      }  
        if(value===result)
        {
          corrected++;
        }
        if(id==last)
      {
        databox.innerHTML='<h3> You have given '+corrected+' correct answers out of '+last;
      }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either ...

- Change `if(value===result)` into `if(value==result)`
- or provide the result parameter as a string: `checkAnswer('1',1,0)`instead of `checkAnser(1,1,0)`.

Running code: https://jsfiddle.net/5y41y4v6/1/

If you are curious why, check the [Difference between == and === in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript)

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem my putting:

-> Change if(value===result) into if(value==result)

If you are curious why, check the Difference between == and === in JavaScript